# Swift Error (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION)

Tags: swift

I have one error that I can't fix. I am new to using Swift so I am a little lost here.[image]

```
Basic Swift
```

Comment: Your `TimeLabel` is `nil`. Maybe the IBOutlet is not connected?

Comment: It would actually be better if you posted the code itself instead of taking a picture, but that's not mandatory. And I think the problem is that in the output logs, it said "Unexpectedly found nil". Maybe what Thilo said - your TimeLabel is nil.

Comment: If this question is answered, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

`super.viewDidLoad()` should be called before you start writing code in the function. Basically, the super function is calling the behind-the-scenes viewDidLoad function before you run your own code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    TimeLabel.text = "\(counter)"
}
```

Also, notice the way that I wrote the string. This is called string interpolation and is the correct way to place variables in a string. For example: "The value is (counter * 2/3)"